# Javascript two dimensional array iternation

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

You have people coming over, and pizza is on the menu. The problem is, each person only likes certain toppings. And the more people come over, the more pizza you’ll need. To help you figure out how much pizza you should order, and what toppings to get, you are going to create a JavaScript program.

Your HTML page should list the following people, how many slices they eat, and their topping preferences.

//Pizza preferences that are hard coded in

The program should ask who is coming over. After all of the guests have been typed in, the program will announce how many slices of pizza you’ll need, and what toppings you can choose from for this particular group of people. This information should be accurate no matter which of the people are added to the guest list. If the people that are coming over can’t agree on any toppings, the program should point out that you need to just get plain pizza.

```js
//Dinner plans assignment

       var nameSliceTop = [];
       var totalSlice = 0;
       var aceptableTopping = ["pepperoni", "bacon", "ham", "pineapple", "onion", "peppers", "extra cheese", "sausage", "olives"
         , "mushroom", "plain"]
       
      nameSliceTop[0] = ["jane", 2, "mushroom", "onion", "peppers", "olives"];
      nameSliceTop[1] = ["lisa", 3, "pepperoni", "ham", "pineapple"];
      nameSliceTop[2] = ["taylor", 3, "extra cheese", "pepperoni", "sausage", "bacon"];
      nameSliceTop[3] = ["chris", 2, "mushroom", "sausage", "bacon", "ham", "onion", "peppers"];
      nameSliceTop[4] = ["alyssa", 1, "pepperoni", "bacon"];
      nameSliceTop[5] = ["will", 2, "extra cheese", "sausage", "bacon", "onion", "peppers", "olives"];
      nameSliceTop[6] = ["jessica", 2, "pepperoni", "bacon", "ham", "pineapple", "onion", "peppers"];
      
      function outputPizza() {
        for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
          if (document.getElementById(nameSliceTop[i][0]).checked === true) {
            totalSlice += nameSliceTop[i][1];
          }  
        }  
        document.getElementById("dinnerPlansTwo").innerHTML += "You will need " + totalSlice + " slices for your guests." + "<br/>";
        totalSlice = 0;
          
        for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
          if (document.getElementById(nameSliceTop[i][0]).checked === true) {
          
            for(x = 2; x < nameSliceTop.length; x++) {
            
              for (y = 0; y < aceptableTopping.length; y++) {
                if (aceptableTopping[y].indexOf(nameSliceTop[i][x]) == -1) { 
                  aceptableToping.splice(y, 1);
                }  
              }      
            }        
          }
        } 
      
        document.getElementById("dinnerPlansTwo").innerHTML += "Your agreeable options include:";
      
        for (z = 0; z < aceptableTopping.length; z++) {
          document.getElementById("dinnerPlansTwo").innerHTML += " " + aceptableTopping[z] + " ";
        }
        
      }
```

```html
<!-- Dinner Plans assighment -->
      <p id="dinnerPlans"> Dinnner Plans Assighment: </p>
      
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Check if attending</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Slices</th>
            <th>Aceptable Toppings</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="jane"></td>
            <td>Jane</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>mushroom, onion, peppers, olives</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="lisa"></td>
            <td>Lisa</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>pepperoni, ham, pineapple</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="taylor"></td>
            <td>Taylor</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>extra cheese, pepperoni, sausage, bacon</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="chris"></td>
            <td>Chris</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>mushroom, sausage, bacon, ham, onion, peppers</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="alyssa"></td>
            <td>Alyssa</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>pepperoni, bacon</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="will"></td>
            <td>Will</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>extra cheese, sausage, bacon, onion, peppers, olives</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="jessica"></td>
            <td>Jessica</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>pepperoni, bacon, ham, pineapple, onion, peppers</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      
      <button onclick="outputPizza()">Submit selected textboxes</button>
      
      <p id="dinnerPlansTwo"><br/></p>
```

Comment: "I'm trying to complete a homework problem"...  so honest, love it

Comment: @JulianSoro Hey, homework or not you can only bang your head against a problem so long. What made this one even worse is my background in Java. Here I go building arrays that javascript and HTML aren't built for......

Comment: I'm taking a look at it, will post when I figure it out

Comment: So dont we need to know how many slices a pizza is made of? Once we have whole pizzas with correct toppings we can then consider putting toppings on half of pizzas correct? This is a tough problem. Ughhh lol. Also, we have data in two-d array and we are pulling data from the DOM. We have to eliminate the two-d array's data. We populate that using the DOM. I think I'd use jQuery and use each

Comment: @yardpenalty I agree. Not only did it screw with me because of my previous background not gelling well, it screwed with me cause it was downright ambiguous. That's kinda been a theme in this course. Ughhhh is right. I eventually just decided they didn't care about whole pizzas and just wanted a number of slices with universally accepted toppings. It took me awhile though. I think you'd agree that most people don't think of ordering pizza that way.

Comment: @Matt9878, you will find that you will get better at identifying issues like this. Be patient because hard work and dedication will come with self-fulfillment and you will find that when you complete challenges it becomes rewarding and addicting. Good luck :-P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had several issues in your code. Let me list them out, but before I do,

Here's a link to my [fiddle: jsfiddle.net/6f0ctoco](https://jsfiddle.net/6f0ctoco/)

Issues with your original code:

1. In jsfiddle, I was getting "outputPizza is not defined error". This might not be
   the case for you, but I had to overcome it by setting the function to the global window
   object, `window.outputPizza = function outputPizza() { //...`
2. You had a typo for `acceptableTopping` in the last for loop. The spelling didn't 
   match the rest of the script.
3. You were using `acceptableTopping.splice()`. Splice will remove items from
   the `acceptableTopping` array. Instead, you want to store your acceptable toppings
   in a new array. I stored them in `currentAcceptableToppings` instead.
4. Because you were not properly tracking or checking for the acceptable toppings, 
   there was some significant changes made in the `outputPizza` function

   - I track the checked person's preferences in an array called `preferences`
   - for each preference in the array, I check each topping to see if they are acceptable
     by running a filter over preferences, then comparing the lengths of filterPreferences & preferences
5. I use `document.getElementById("dinnerPlansTwo").innerHTML` only once to simplify the output printing

Tip: I used Array.forEach, because the syntax is just nicer to read than having too many `for` loops.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'll use this as a guide, not a copy and paste, so I can still develop as a coder. I think the first thing Ill do after this course is ensure that the course I select has better a development environment. It wouldn't have fixed everything but it would catch the stupid mismatched variable and better inform me of errors. My intention with splice was to remove the bad and keep the good, nonetheless, your solutions cleaner. In another answer, the use of objects over arrays was suggested. What do you think of that? Thanks again.

Comment: It can be more helpful to use objects, so the keys are standard and named, instead of having to know that index 0 is the person name

Answer (score 0):

A better approach might be to define possible party attendees as Objects, not arrays:

```
var people = [{
  name: "jane",
  slices: 2,
  toppings: ["mushroom", "onion", "peppers", "olives"]
}, {
  ...
}];
```

Then, as you iterate over your selected people, you can add slices. After you iterate over everyone, you'd have to [deduplicate the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array), but this is a cleaner approach and only needs to be done once per button click.

<strike>Additionally, you only need to iterate over your `people` array once: with each iteration, if the person is selected, add the slices to a `totalSlices` variable and the person's topping preferences to the `acceptableToppings` array variable.</strike>

If "acceptable toppings" means *everyone* prefers the topping, not just *anyone*, then I'd go with a nested for loop like you have above:

```
// Loop through all possible toppings
for (i = 0; i < aceptableTopping.length; i++) {
  // Loop through all people
  for (j = 0; j < people.length; j++) {
    // If any person's topping preferences do NOT include the topping in question, "pop" (remove) it
    if (people[j]["toppings"].indexOf(aceptableTopping[i]) < 0) {
      aceptableTopping.pop(aceptableTopping[i]);
      continue;
    }
  }
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the input. When I first started thinking about the problems I considered that. My only question is this: How do you ensure that the aceptableToppings variable only contains toppings in common with all selected persons. This would list toppings that individuals like, but wouldn't find commonality. Feel free to tell me I'm wrong. I hope I am because your right, that would be a much cleaner solution.

Comment: Ah, if acceptable toppings means _everyone_ prefers that topping, then I'd go with a nested for loop, similar to what you have above:

`
    // Loop through all possible toppings
    for (i = 0; i < aceptableTopping.length; i++) {
      // Loop through all people
      for (j = 0; j < people.length; j++) {
        // If any person's topping preferences do NOT include the topping in question, remove it
        if (people[j]["toppings"].indexOf(aceptableTopping[i]) < 0) {
          aceptableTopping.pop(aceptableTopping[i]);
          continue;
        }
      }
    }
`

Comment: Thanks for the further input. Take a look at the solution I accepted. It goes a bit of a different way but it is cleaner. Thanks again for the assistance. I sure as hell wasn't going to figure this out on my own.